# getting exception IndexOutOfBoundsException FragmentManagerImpl after sharing something to the apps

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sharing

I get this exception just after sharing content to my app and just in the case when the app is already started.
If I start the app directly all the things work good.
If I share something to my app and the app is not already running all the things work good.
They don't work just in the first case.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_real_debrid);

    LoginStore.init(getApplicationContext());
    AnalyticsManager.init(getApplicationContext());
    RDDownloadManager.init(this);
    ResponseHandlerManager.init(this);
    AppRater.app_launched(this, getString(R.string.app_name));
    layout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    setFragment(FragmentList.findFragmentById(0).getFragment(), false);
    if (layout instanceof DrawerLayout) {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) layout;
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        supportActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                if (supportActionBar.getTitle().equals(mDrawerTitle))
                    supportActionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                mTitle = supportActionBar.getTitle();
                supportActionBar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
    Credentials c = LoginStore.getCredential();
    if (c.getLogin() == null || c.getPasswd() == null)
    {
        Intent loginIntent;         
        loginIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivityForResult(loginIntent, 0);
    }

}

public void setFragment(IFragment mFragment, boolean mAnimate) {
    final FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mContent = mFragment;
    if (mAnimate)
        mFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_in, R.anim.fragment_out);
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, (Fragment) mContent).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    supportActionBar.setTitle(mContent.getMenuTitle());
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735): Process: fr.free.ligol.realdebrid, PID: 22735
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:481)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeInactive(FragmentManager.java:1158)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1201)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:639)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-20 02:41:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Comment: Nop, no solutions at this time, but since this time my code as change and I've recoded this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Fragment list like :

```
FragmentList.findFragmentById(0);
```

And at the index 0 there is no fragment added so it is showing outOFBoundsException.

Check the list size and then retrieve the data from the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try on rollback version of my code and that a part of a solution to my problem. So I'm going to validate your answer.